# Автоматический перевод видео

Tags: нейронные-сети, поиск-программ, перевод

Есть ли сервисы, нейросети для автоматического перевода длинных видео по ссылке, бесплатные или за вменяемую стоимость? Из того, что я видел ничего нормального нет. Яндекс браузер не подходит, т.к. слишком долгие видео он не переводит (хотел посмотреть лекцию freecodecamp с youtube).